# Django FormView does not have form context

Tags: django, view, django-templates, formview, django-context

When defining a FormView derived class:

```
class PrefsView(FormView):
    template_name = "prefs.html"
    form_class = MyForm         # What's wrong with this?
    def get(self,request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['pagetitle'] = 'My special Title'
        context['form'] = MyForm    # Why Do I have to write this?
        return render(self.request,self.template_name,context)
```

I expected the line `context['form'] = MyForm` was not needed, since `form_class` is defined, but without it `{{ form }}` is not passed to template.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the context, `form` should be the instantiated form, not the form class. Defining the `form_class` is completely separate from including the instantiated form in the context data.

For the example you've given, I think you'd be better to override `get_context_data` instead of `get`.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PrefsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['pagetitle'] = 'My special Title'
    return context
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good advice, but still does not answer the qeustion, why do I need that line? In several examples I see the use of form_class instead.

Comment: In practice, you say defining `form_class` is completely separate from including the instantiated form in template. So maybe I didn't fully understand all this, for what purpose one should define `form_class`?

Comment: You *don't* need that line if you don't override `get`. If you do, then you're preventing the default implementation from including the form, so of course you need to include it yourself.

Comment: When using a `FormView`, [`form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class) defines what type of form to instantiate. The `get` method instantiates a a form, and includes it in the context. Since you are overriding `get`, you need to include `form` in the context as well. Because you seem to be overriding the `get` method to add an extra variable to the template context, I suggested overriding `get_context_data` instead - that way you don't need to worry about the other stuff that the `get` method does.

Comment: But I was returning `super()` :(
Oh well, I guess it was some of the inherited classes' fault.. Thank you for this!