# Django ChoiceField get choice value in template

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a radio button which is a yes / no.

```
YES_NO_CHOICES = [(False,'No'),(True,'Yes')]
```

I also have a choicefield in my ModelForm

```
show_game = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=YES_NO_CHOICES, required=True)
```

I dislike the HTML provided by Django; hence, I made a custom html with css which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="id_show_game" id="{{radio.id_for_label}}" value="{{radio.id}}" {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{radio.id_for_label}}">{{radio.choice_label}}</label>
</div>
```

However, `value` is appearing empty:

[image: proof]

How do I access the `value` of `radio` which is a ChoiceField WITHOUT using the template provided by Django in the following tags:

1. `{{radio}}` <- result from `{% for radio in gameInfoForm.show_game %}`
2. `{{form}}` <- ModelForm type

Comment: Hi, I think this is what you need
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.get_context

Comment: @AliAsghari would you be able to provide an example on **how** and **where** to use it?

Comment: Hello @CraftedGaming here you can find https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687781/14457833